# How can we talk about the mass of $W^\pm$ bosons when they don't diagonalise the mass matrix?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, standard-model, gauge-theory, electroweak

In the electroweak lagrangian, after symmetry breaking we get $W^1_\mu,W^2\mu,W^3\mu$ and $B_\mu$ bosons. These fields don't however diagonalise the mass matrix $\frac{\partial^2V}{\partial\phi_i\partial\phi_j}$ (where the $\phi_i$ are one of the fields, in this case $W$ or $B$).

As I understand it, the mass matrix is already diagonal wrt. $W^1$ and $W^2$, but not $W^3$ and $B$. I understand that we can take a linear combination of the $W^3$ and $B$ fields to diagonalise the mass matrix entirely, but then we further take a linear combination of $W^1$ and $W^2$ to give $W^\pm$ instead in order to work in states of definite charge.

My confusion is that with respect to the $W^\pm$ fields, the mass matrix isn't diagonal! So how can we talk about their masses?

I'm not sure how to interpret the "linear combination of fields" in terms of the mass matrix. I was thinking of it as a change of basis, but since $W^1$ and $W^2$ have the same mass, on their subspace the mass matrix should be proportional to the identity, and doesn't this mean that any change of basis should leave the mass matrix diagonal?

Comment: I'm confused... Does the last paragraph not perfectly answer your question? The mass matrix is proportional to the identity so all vectors are eigenvectors with the same eigenvalue?

Comment: @AXensen When I write the lagrangian in terms of $W^\pm$, the mass term is $W^+W^-$, and I'm assuming the mass matrix elements should be given now by $\partial^2V/\partial W^\pm\partial W^\pm$. Or should I still be differentiating wrt $W^1$ and $W^2$?

Comment: I see your point now. I don't know how to answer the question from that perspective.

Comment: What do you believe a mass term for $W^+$ should look like?

Comment: @CosmasZachos For a mass term with no mixing I would expect it to be quadratic, ie $(W^+)^2$. As it is the term $W^+W^-$ has $\partial^2V\partial W^\pm\partial W^\pm$ with evals 1 and -1, suggesting to me these terms have opposite mass. Unlike $\partial^2V/\partial W^i\partial W^j$ which gives evals $1$ and $1$.

Comment: This is wrong! The mass term must conserve charge! Recall the h.c. of $W^+$ is $W^-$. How do you write the mass term of a charged scalar? The same mass term , $W^-W^+$  , destroys a $W^+$ and recreates it, and, likewise for $W^-$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Ah okay, so for a charged scalar we write $\phi^\dagger\phi$ and here $W^-=(W^+)^\dagger$ so $W^+W^-=(W^+)^\dagger W^+$. So there's something off with my idea of the mass matrix since it gives the wrong answer for $\phi^\dagger\phi$ too. $(W^+)^\dagger W^+$ *looks* like a mass term to me, but I'm not sure how to correct my definition of the mass matrix to account for this. Should one of the derivatives be conjugated?

Comment: Yes, that's one way of doing it. Review your basic QFT text...

Comment: This also reminds of the chiral representation of the free Dirac fermion. The mass term links left chiral and right chiral, and is thus also not diagonal.